# messageSource doesn't replace all arguments in template

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, template-engine, resourcebundle

I have code:

```
messageSource.getMessage("some.key",new Object[]{30,31},Constants.LOCALE)
```

and key inside property file:

```
some.key=Csv header length ({0}) doesn't correspond the mapping file size {1} .
```

but result is strange:

```
Csv header length (30) doesn't correspond the mapping file size {1} .
```

Fisrt variable was successfully replaced but second - not.

Why does second argument was not resolved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is because you have a single quote in the message that you have not escaped.

See https://www.mscharhag.com/java/resource-bundle-single-quote-escaping for an example of your problem.

Comment: Unbelievable. I can't believe my IDE doesn't warn me about this. Anyway, thanks for the solution.

Comment: I'd like to add that to escape a single quote, you must add a second consecutive single quote. In other words, use `''` instead of `'`, where the former is **not** a double quote.